# Schrödinger's cat experience: how many cats are alive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-states, quantum-measurements, schroedingers-cat

In the Schrödinger cat experiment, I know that the cat is in the superposition of two states, let us say:

$$\alpha(t)\, |\mbox{alive}\rangle + \beta(t)\, |\mbox{dead}\rangle$$

After a measurement, there is a probability $| \alpha(t) |^2$ that the cat is alive, and a probability $| \beta(t) |^2$ that the cat is dead. I wonder if, before the measurement, the number of cats alive has a meaning. Is there somehow $\alpha(t)\, |1\rangle + \beta(t)\, |0\rangle$ cats alive? Or the number of cats alive is simply undefined?

Here is my point. I wonder, during the experiment, if the number of cats alive is a continuous function, if $\alpha, \beta$ are continuous functions of $t$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'the number of cats' - either dead or alive? What is the difference between the two (or four) basis states you're using?

Comment: I mean a reasonable "quantic number", which is in a superposition of standard numbers, such that, after a measurement, it is 1 if the cat is alive, 0 if is a cat is dead. $|alive\rangle$, $|dead\rangle$ are the possible observable state for the cat, and $|1\rangle$, $|0\rangle$ would be the possible observable state for the number.

Comment: It seems like you're just attempting to redefine "superposition".  There is no better way to say it than the cats' states are in superposition.  It's not "undefined", they are defined as being in superposition.

Comment: Cats are just an analogy to show how ridiculous far we can stray from reality.

Comment: What @BillAlsept wrote above. It was just a joke by Schrodinger to show how ridiculously far we can stray from reality. Please put your efforts in something more related to reality - physics has a lot to offer on that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the number of cats alive is undefined unless you measure it. The is true for any quantum observable when the system in question is in a superposition of states with different values for that observable. For example, in a double-slit experiment, there is no answer to the question of which slit a particle went through unless you measure it.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation value is the weighted average of outcomes to a measurment. The expectation value need not be a possible outcome to a measurment though. If we take the outcome of the measurmeent in S.'s cat to be the number of alive, then in the original set-up the expectation value is 0.5 cats alive.

If the distribution of possible outomes to a measurement are narrowly peaked around the expectation value the you may be able to treat the expectation value as representing the value of a classical physical quantity. However in situations like S.'s cat which are at the opposite extreme, it is not useful/meaningful to treat the expectation value in such a way: in other words it doesn't make a lot of sense to say there are 0.5 cats alive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one apple and that apple is not red, you have zero red apples.

If you have one cat and that cat is not in the state "alive", you have zero cats in the state "alive".

Zero is a well defined number.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the cat is in the superposition of two states,

This is false. The unfortunate Schrodinger cat is used as **a proxy** for a [Geiger counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter).  Since the poison will be released when a **nuclear decay happens**, the quantum mechanical state, the first level of detecting a decay is a Geiger counter. The cat is collateral damage, irrelevant to the real cause of the probability distribution of which one instance will be the deadly decay.The cat is a macroscopic object, and is either alive or dead  depending on the quantum probabilities of the decay.

> Here is my point. I wonder, during the experiment, if the number of cats alive is a continuous function, if α,β are continuous functions of t?

The nuclear decay probabilities are continuous. As the life or death of the poor cats depends on the continuous decay probabilities of the nuclei, any function you make up will be continuous. But keep in mind that the cat is not described quantum mechanically as it is made up of order $10^{24}$ molecules in a quantum mechanical incoherent state.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your question is false. You do not know that the cat is in a superposition on two states, one in which it is alive and another in which it is dead. Schrödinger proposed the thought experiment specifically to illustrate that it is absurd to consider an everyday object such as a cat to be in such a superposition.

Answer (score -1):

I’m not a physicist -

It’s understandable that you would think:
“The cat starts out alive. So the bias will be towards being alive, reduced over time.”
Maybe you are thinking of a different theory/expression?
Or you trying to work out if you can mail cats to a friend..

This is an expression of chances of being dead(0) or alive (1) are not 50/50 but 100/100 until the box is opened.

Not a varied state of ‘aliveness’ of 73.6% because (t) has passed.

As mentioned by some others, nothing to do with cats. It’s a metaphor.

“If a tree falls in a forest, and no one was there to hear it, did it make a sound”